# Encode accents and special characters PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a little problem with me php to upload imgs.

I'm making a website where a user may view a preview of the image that goes up, but if the image contains accents goes wrong such as "Nenúfares.jpg" becomes "NenÃºfares.jpg.jpg"

How I can fix this?

Had thought about putting some method to select when an alert comes in. (JS) as containing special characters such as accents, etc ...

Mi Code

PHP:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
$ruta ="tmp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
  $rutafinal =str_replace(" ","_",$ruta); //Change " " for "_"
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$rutafinal);
  echo $rutafinal;


  }
else
  {
     echo "Archivo no valido";
  }
```

JavaScript (AJAX):

```
function previewIMG() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = $("#fileselectInput")[0].files[0];

    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("name", file.name);
    var url ="subir_img_producto.php";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url, true);        
    http.send(formData);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            var result= http.responseText;
            var comprobar= 'tmp';
            if (result.indexOf(comprobar) !== -1) {
                document.getElementById('cuadroIMG').src = http.responseText;
            }else{
                alert(http.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
        <input type="file" id="fileselectInput" onchange="previewIMG()"><br>
    </form>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe just use utf-8 on your website/server?

Comment: database is currently in utf-8, but want to avoid the accents in the files for compatibility etc ... everything is already text fields with "encode" to pick you up right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the utf-8 issue already covered nicely by [Amauri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22987255/532495), another thing you might want to do is this:

replace

```
$ruta ="tmp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$rutafinal =str_replace(" ","_",$ruta); //Change " " for "_"
```

with

```
$ruta      = "tmp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fileExtension = substr($ruta,stripos ($ruta,'.'));
$rutafinal = 'tmp/' . md5(time() . $ruta).'.'.$fileExtension;
```

This will create a [md5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) hash from the current timestamp and your filename as your new filename, thus giving you a better chance that your filename is unique on your system plus getting rid of "special chars".

One thing i like to do is also use the users unique id (if that exists) as an addition to prevent problems when two users upload the same file (*might happen a lot with filenames like avatar.jpeg and such*).

After all, md5 is not collision free so you might have to do some extra work here.
One way to up your chances is to use timestamp driven directories as well:

```
$rutafinal = 'tmp/' . date("Y/m/d/h/i", time()) . '/'. md5(time() . $ruta).'.'.$fileExtension;
```

This would, as an example, put your file in

```
<yourimageuploadfolder>/2014/04/10/14/04/5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3.jpg
```

Comment: I really like your idea, I think I will use, the end of the day it is a temporary route, then the other changes associated with an object.

Comment: the problem is not saved in the path "/ tmp" folder I want and puts another point being to "b511ce7ef7f0c4009bbabf645efa9cba .. jpg"

Comment: @CristianCV you can use `_` instead of `/` so it won't have to create new folders in `tmp` if you do not have permissions to make a directory.

Comment: I have permissions, what happens is that the procedure you have mentioned completely erases the route, should I write "tmp /" to the end result?

Comment: @CristianCV Oh, sorry ... i made an edit to show how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1? You need to use the same encoding of your database. Let's suppose that your page is UTF-8 and your Database is Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1 / 2), you need to convert the data using [utf8_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php) .

I think that you can solve your encode problem forcing you header like:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Yesterday I solved my encode problem like this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Already me database is "utf8_bin", i should write you code in mi php?

Comment: Perhaps your DATABASE is utf-8 but your page don't. Try to force your header utf-8 too (in the beggining of the code before the HTML).

Comment: So try to use functions to convert your database data like utf8_encode or utf8_decode

Comment: I just fix the problem another way, thank you very much for your help anyway :)

Comment: Edit your question with the solution, it can helps a lot of people with he same issue in the future :)

Comment: It just mark the correct answer is the one with a green check mark

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate and [replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) accents by normal chars:

```
$name = str_replace("ú", "u", $name);
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but I'd rather save myself all the lines of all the special characters that exist and not let the user upload something with accents / special characters jejeje